# How to print the values of datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview

i want to print entire rows of an DGV.

this should be done by extracting the values not taking picture...(if you don't understand please comment below)

is there any way i can do this?

Still facing problem...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxqCNfHpYEJlUVg3VW5aZlpHMlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: See [Printing of DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_. And do you know how to print at all? Anything? How would you print "hello, world"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an **absolutely minimal** code example.

It prints all rows of a dgv, including simple headers and footers..

You need to add a `PrintDocument printDocument1` to your form.

Also a `Button cb_printPreview`.

```
// a few variables to keep track of things across pages:
int nextPageToPrint = -1;
int linesOnPage = -1;
int linesPrinted = -1;
int maxLinesOnPage = -1;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, 
                                      System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // for each fresh page:
    linesOnPage = 0;
    nextPageToPrint++;

    // a short reference to the DataGridView we want to print
    DataGridView DGV = yourDataGridView;

    // I prefer mm, pick your own unit!
    e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;

    // I want to print the columns at these fixed positions
    // the first one is the left margin, 
    // the last one a dummy at the right page margin
    int[] tabStops = new int[4] {15, 30, 100, 190};

    // I want only one column to be right-aligned:
    List<int> rightAlignedCols = new List<int>() { 1 };

    // we need to keep track of the horizontal position
    // this is also the top margin:
    float y = 35f;
    // we add a little space between the lines:
    float leading = 1.5f;
    // we will need to measure the texts we print:
    SizeF size = Size.Empty;
    // we use only one font:
    using (Font font = new Font("Consolas", 13f))
    {
        // a simple header:
        e.Graphics.DrawString("List " + printDocument1.DocumentName, 
                               font, Brushes.Black, 50, y);
        y += size.Height + 15;

        // I loop over the all rows:
        for (int row = linesPrinted; row < DGV.Rows.Count; row++)
        {

            // I print a light gray bar over every second line:
            if (row % 2 == 0) 
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gainsboro, 
                tabStops[0], y - leading / 2, e.PageBounds.Width - 25, size.Height);

            // I print all (3) columns in black, unless they're empty:
            for (int col = 0; col < DGV.ColumnCount; col++)
                if (DGV[0, row].Value != null)
                {
                    string text = DGV[col, row].FormattedValue.ToString();
                    size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, font, 9999);
                    float x = tabStops[col];
                    if (rightAlignedCols.Contains(col) ) 
                        x = tabStops[col + 1] - size.Width;
                    // finally we print an item:
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, x, y);
                }
           // advance to next line:
            y += size.Height + leading;
            linesOnPage++;
            linesPrinted++;
            if (linesOnPage > maxLinesOnPage)   // page is full
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;      // more to come
                break;                      // leave the rows loop! 
            }         
       }
       e.Graphics.DrawString("Page " + nextPageToPrint, font, 
                               Brushes.Black, tabStops[3] -20, y + 15);

    }
}

private void cb_printPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintPreviewDialog PPVdlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
    PPVdlg.Document = printDocument1;
    PPVdlg.ShowDialog();
}

private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, 
                                       System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    // create a demo title for the page header:
    printDocument1.DocumentName = " Suppliers as of  " 
                                  + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    // initial values for a print job:
    nextPageToPrint = 0;
    linesOnPage = 0;
    maxLinesOnPage = 30;
    linesPrinted = 0;
}
```

The actual printing can be triggered from the `PrintPreviewDialog`.

There is also a `PrintDialog` and a `PrintPreview` control for more options.

Obviously one can add many more things, including graphics, multiple fonts etc, but this should give you an idea.. For full tutorials please look refer to the WWW & MSDN!

Comment: Thank you TaW... but still facing problem... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxqCNfHpYEJlUVg3VW5aZlpHMlk/view?usp=sharing  please bear with me if this one seems so obvious...

Comment: Haha! (Sorry ,-) Please try to not just copy but also understand the code! I bet you have less than 30 rows in your dgv? change the start and/ or end conditions to suit your case. You may even loop over a List<DataGridViewRows> of some selected rows or any other collection of rows you want top print..

Comment: are you online? my email id is senthilvivek93@gmail.com please can we chat?

Comment: Not really, I have to go. Sorry! (What chat medium would you have suggested btw, I don't think you can use SO chat, can you?) - I'll be back in a few hours..

Comment: whatever means necessary... team viewer or google hangouts...(that's why i gave you my mail id)... please don't hung up on me bro... i need to finish this... i am past deadline...

Comment: Hi, I'm back. Not familiar with any of thoses chats, though..

Comment: that problem is solved... but i have something else...

Comment: i did my project using mysql (WAMP)for database, now i need to export it as software package... i know it won't run without a database... help me... its taking forever to discuss like this... least give me you email-id... please...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this problem. You will have to search elsewhere. - BTW: I have updated my answer to allow for multiple pages with headers and footers. If your printing problem is solved, please accept the answer!

Comment: Hi @TaW. I used your metod and it worked grate. The only problem is that my columns are too wide to fit a page. (I want to fit it to the page size.)

Comment: If you study the code you can see the tab stops I defined as an example. For narrower column you should adapt those. If that still won't fit you an need to use a narrower fornt like 'Arial Narrow' or reduce the font size..

Comment: thanks, that helps :)