# Printing Datagrid view in C# in windows form application

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem while doing a project in C# of Inventory management system. 
Here I have to print some datagrid view with PRINT button by a printer. I am facing problem while printing the datagridView.
I had the code i am giving below. Can you please modify the code to print a datagridview with testing with a printer.

Here's my code :

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170); // all sizes are converted from mm to inches & then multiplied by 100.
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
            //pd.PrinterSettings = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while printing", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        if (t < 1)
        {
            ev.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1., new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 225);
            t++;
            if (t < 1)
            {
                ev.HasMorePages = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ev.HasMorePages = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448856/how-to-print-the-values-of-datagridview-in-c/27453694#27453694)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.I have tried it but getting the following problem.
**An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.**
Can you help me with that problem?Where I need to modify the code?Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which line brings up the exception? Also: How many rows and how many columns does your DGV have?

Comment: In the following line I faced the problem.

`if (DGV[0, row].Value != null)`
  
I have 10 columns and The row number is not fixed...

Comment: OK, you should use the debugger to find out why this fails. Most likely you have not __hooked up__ the `printDocument1_BeginPrint` event; that would mean that `linesPrinted` remains at `-1`. Since that's the starting point for `row` on each page, it will fail..

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

I'm not that advanced with printing but I used a PrintDialog like this:

```
    private void PrintDoc()
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog(); //make a printDialog object

        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument(); // make a print doc object

        printDialog.Document = printDocument; //document for printing is printDocument

        printDocument.PrintPage += printDocument_PrintPage; //event handler fire



        DialogResult result = printDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument.Print();
        }

    }
```

If that doesn't help, according to you error and your code I'm not sure if the `index` it is talking about comes from the dataGridView or from the ev.graphics, but I think you are missing some code?

```
private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    Graphics graphic = ev.Graphics;
    foreach (DataRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string text = row.ToString() //or whatever you want from the current row
            graphic.DrawString(text,new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 225);
        }
}
```

Comment: I used the code in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448856/how-to-print-the-values-of-datagridview-in-c/27453694#)  and error is in the following line 
**if (DGV[0, row].Value != null)**

Comment: in your `ev.DrawString` you just have `Datagridview.,` Does your datagridview have any data?

Comment: Yes.In the datagridview i have data

Answer (score 0):

If you want the simplest way to print. try this: [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Print-DataGridView-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

you also can use [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView) for more functionality.