# Not able to print content of data grid by Printer

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, datagridview

I tried the code given below but it does not print grid content, it only prints the border.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap dataGridViewImage = new Bitmap(this.tickGridBulkAssign.Width, this.tickGridBulkAssign.Height);

    tickGridBulkAssign.DrawToBitmap(dataGridViewImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.tickGridBulkAssign.Width, this.tickGridBulkAssign.Height));

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(dataGridViewImage, 0, 0);
}

protected override void toolBarButtonPrint_Click()
{
    printDocument1.Print();
}
```

Comment: did u chk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463136/printing-datagrid-view-in-c-sharp-in-windows-form-application

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448856/how-to-print-the-values-of-datagridview-in-c/27453694#27453694

Comment: Thanks,second link works for me :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the values of datagridview in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448856/how-to-print-the-values-of-datagridview-in-c)

Comment: I guess it would be better u close/delete this question