# Printing datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

I am working with a project and here i need to print the datagrid view with a printer.I used the following code.

```
 private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170); // all sizes are converted from mm to inches & then multiplied by 100.
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.pd_PrintPage);
            //pd.PrinterSettings = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while printing", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        if (t < 1)
        {
            ev.Graphics.DrawString("Hello YouTube", new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 225);

            t++;
            if (t < 1)
            {
                ev.HasMorePages = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ev.HasMorePages = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now this code print can print hello youtube or whichever we give in that string.But we need to print a datagridview instead of it.So, which portion of the code should we change?

Comment: Look in Codeproject. There was a good DGV print project.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you looking for else [clickhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448856/how-to-print-the-values-of-datagridview-in-c/27453694#27453694)

```
private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("A4", 827, 1170); // all sizes are converted from mm to inches & then multiplied by 100.
            pd.PrintPage += printDocument_PrintPage; //event handler fire
            //pd.PrinterSettings = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while printing", ex.ToString());
        }
    }



 private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        Graphics graphic = ev.Graphics;
        foreach (DataRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string text = row.ToString() //or whatever you want from the current row
                graphic.DrawString(text,new Font("Times New Roman", 14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 225);
            }
    }
```

Comment: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in LKPK.exe
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.**

This problem is shown..Can you say why this occurs.Previously I couldn't test it with a printer so I thought it was ok. But After testing with a printer I found an error and tested the code.Then I came across this error. @ Midhun Mundayadan

Answer (score 0):

use for loop to iterate through datagridview contents and instead of helloyoutube,specify the columname whose contents has to be dispalyed

```
 for(int i=0;i<dg.rows.count;i++)
 {
  ev.Graphics.DrawString(dg.rows[i].cells["columnname"].value, new Font("Times New Roman",               14, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, 20, 225);
 }
```