# Printing issue with datagridview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi all I have written a code to print the datagridview rows, it is working fine but I am not seeing data in my second page can some one help me, here is the code that I have tried I am having 90 rows I tried with some other articles published but no luck

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string constring = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                        //Set Columns Count
                        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

                        //Add Columns
                        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "CustomerId";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Customer Id";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "CustomerID";

                        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Contact Name";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Name";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ContactName";

                        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Country";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Country";
                        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Country";
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int height, width = 0;
        StringFormat str = new StringFormat();
        str.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        str.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        str.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2.5f);
        System.Drawing.Font fntString = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        System.Drawing.Font fnthead = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold);
        height = 100;
        while (s < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (height > e.MarginBounds.Height)
            {

                height = 100;
                width = 100;
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
            }


            height += dataGridView1.Rows[s].Height;


            if (s % 2 == 0)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 70, (s * 89) + 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 100, (s * 89) + 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 70, (s * 89) + 40);
            }
            else
            { // Right Column

                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 370, ((s - 1) * 89) + 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 400, ((s - 1) * 89) + 20);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[s].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 370, ((s - 1) * 89) + 40);
            }
            s++;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument1.Print();
    }
```

Proposed answer

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

            int y = 0;
            System.Drawing.Font fntString = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
            while (printIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count &&
                   y + dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Height < e.MarginBounds.Height)
            {
                // print your stuff, y is where you are on the page vertically


                if (printIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 370, ((printIndex - 1) * 89) + 20);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 400, ((printIndex - 1) * 89) + 20);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 370, ((printIndex - 1) * 89) + 40);

                }


                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 370, ((printIndex - 1) * 89) + 20);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 400, ((printIndex - 1) * 89) + 20);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString(), fntString, Brushes.Black, 370, ((printIndex - 1) * 89) + 40);
                }

                y += dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Height;
                ++printIndex;
            }

            e.HasMorePages = printIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42925/Printing-Multiple-Pages-and-Tabular-Printing

Comment: I guess you can try this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448856/how-to-print-the-values-of-datagridview-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PrintPage event is for every page you want to print. That means your For...Each loop won't work since you are telling the printer to print everything on the current page.

You have to have a variable outside the PrintPage method scope to keep track of which row index you are currently on:

```
int printIndex;

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) {

  int y = 0;

  while (printIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count && 
         y + dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Height < e.MarginBounds.Height) {

    // print your stuff, y is where you are on the page vertically

    y += dataGridView1.Rows[printIndex].Height;
    ++printIndex;
  }

  e.HasMorePages = printIndex < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
}
```

Use the BeginPrint event to reset your printIndex value:

```
private void printDocument1_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e) {
  printIndex = 0;
}
```

If you add another variable, such as int printPage;, you can now know which page you are currently printing, too, by incrementing that value in the PrintPage event.

Comment: Hi as per the given answer I have tried as per the update question but I am not seeing any data in second page and even the data is getting merged

Comment: Hi Bala one small help I would like to print odd rows on left and even rows on right how can I change this code